# Memory usage of CoreData with multiple ManagedObjectContexts

Tags: ios, core-data

I have seen many examples of using CoreData with multiple ManagedObjectContexts (in the new-ish iOS5+ Parent/Child way), for example:

```
//
//          persistentStore (on disk)
//                 |
//   persistentManagedObjectContext (exclusively for saving)
//                 |
//   mainThreadManagedObjectContext (for managedObject's used on the mainThread)
//                 |
//      childManagedObjectContext (created "on the fly" for background task, and destroyed when saving is done)
//
```

1. Am I correct in thinking that in this 3 tier approach above, each fetch performed on the child MOC will result in at least 3 copies of any objects read being held in memory, 
   one in each of the MOC (plus possibly more in any internal messaging CoreData uses between MOCs)?
2. If I had a background task that reads some data (eg an image), does some processing (eg create a thumbnail) and writes to the database, but does not directly/immediately update the UI, then
   am I correct in thinking that this approach would not be suitable either, since updates would needlessly be going through the main context and thus the main thread and affecting the UIs performance.